# Remove gap between UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` with 10 cells.

I've changed my `UITableView`'s background color to red, but now there is a small red line between each cell (in addition to the separator line).

I need to disable this small gap between the cells that the background color won't be visible between the cells.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]
Does anybody know how can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: once check the height for row and height for header or fotter. it will be better if you can post screenshot

Comment: Do you want to remove separator line of tableView?

Comment: @ismail cell's height is 44px (default), header and footer are both 0px.
Added a screenshot, please take a look

Comment: @MehulSojitra No, I want the separator, I don't want the gap between the cells that reveals the tableView's background color (in my case, red)

Comment: Generally you wont be able to see the background color of table through the cells, there is some height issue.

Comment: @RahulPatel what can be the problem?

Comment: Is this your custom cell? If possible can you show your code?

Comment: do you know how to use View Hierarchy. In that you can see layers of views in that you can detect which view is that red lines

Answer (score 0):

By going through your snap shot it is clear to me :

- there is a separator which is a thin black line with custom offset set. That you can removed as mentioned in one of the answers.
- other one is there is a red colour appearing in between cells. Please check is your tableView cell has clearcolor set. As you can see the last cell doesn't have red coloured line in bottom. Which i feel is you have a label over your cell which starts some pixel below the actual cell starts and hence you are able to see red coloured line over all cell excepts bottom of last cell.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

In storyBoard select your tableView and then select "Attribute inspector"(at Right side) then Set "Seperator"->"None"

You can also do it by programatically -

`UITableView` property `separatorStyle`. Make sure the property is set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and you're set.

example -

```
  [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Comment: Same problem. I happens in addition to the separator line

Answer (score -1):

Try this  in `viewdidload:`

```
 self.tableview.backgroundcolor =[UIColor clearColor];
```

or

```
self.tableview.backgroundcolor =[UIColor whitecolor];

 [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```